# Custom Live Agent Chat Window Bubble Styling

Tags: liveagent, chat

I'm not a web dev so styling the custom chat window has been a pain. I've made a lot of progress but found it very difficult to get the operator and client bubbles to appear. Here's my stab at it so far. What do I need to do to get something like the below picture?

[image: custom chat]

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" controller="LiveChatRemoter">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d2myx53yhj7u4b.cloudfront.net/sites/default/files/cdn/css/http/css_BClfAajFTZrz8iHm6NpTgVziqeVxoNg5vrjSu228e9k.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d2myx53yhj7u4b.cloudfront.net/sites/default/files/cdn/css/http/css_rs-rZE2a4RBXwrsBQZF9eBxv64OlwGNxeuFaGsyQoIo.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d2myx53yhj7u4b.cloudfront.net/sites/default/files/cdn/css/http/css_EhcqQluFhABuvDSL0ibB5W0cjRSWkcosg2Jnjlbyk5Q.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d2myx53yhj7u4b.cloudfront.net/sites/default/files/cdn/css/http/css_qujiGCCfKZICKxfRZV7A15vGqBNyjMAhIEHiP-z3MAI.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d2myx53yhj7u4b.cloudfront.net/sites/default/files/cdn/css/http/css_zzsI6DK2Iz_ssmMQ_h_WRrDkgEMqGcoap_xlSrT-xzc.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d2myx53yhj7u4b.cloudfront.net/sites/default/files/cdn/css/http/css_wWCoLmmVl7Z4mrkVARZonI1F_8JVvDnQUxkOsrh5o2s_salesforce-chat.css.css" media="screen"/>
<style>

    html {
        padding: 20px;
    }

    body {
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #waitingMessage {
        color: white;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
        display: none;
    }

    #liveAgentClientChat.liveAgentStateWaiting #waitingMessage {
        display: table;
    }

    .liveAgentSaveButton {
        float: left;
    }

    .liveAgentEndButton {
        float: right;
    }

    .liveAgentSaveButton, .liveAgentEndButton, .liveAgentSendButton {
        font-family: "proxima_nova_sbold", "proxima_nova_sbold_cyrillic", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        display: inline-block;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 0;
        border-radius: 3px;
        text-shadow: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    }

    .liveAgentSaveButton, .liveAgentEndButton {
        z-index: 2;
        width: 75px;
        height: 20px;
        bottom: 5px;
    }

    .liveAgentChatInput {
        height: 30px;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #000;
        font-family: "proxima_nova_sbold", "proxima_nova_sbold_cyrillic", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        line-height: 1.5rem;
        padding: 2px 0 2px 4px;
        background: #fff;
        display: block;
        /*display: inline-block;*/
        width: 99%;
    }

    .liveAgentSendButton {
        /*display: block;*/
        width: 60px;
        height: 30px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: -67px;
        background: #6dad3f;
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, left, right);
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6dad3f, #498d1a);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6dad3f, #498d1a);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6dad3f, #498d1a);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6dad3f, #498d1a);
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #6dad3f, #498d1a);
        -webkit-appearance: push-button;
        color: #fff;
        line-height: 1.5rem;
    }

    #liveAgentChatLog {
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        top: 0;
        position: absolute;
        overflow-y: auto;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        border: none;
    }

    .client {
        text-align: right;
    }

    span.client + span {
        text-align: right;
    }

    #liveAgentChatLogText .name {
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 1em;
        line-height: 1.2;
        display: block;
        white-space: pre;
    }

    #liveAgentChatLogText p {
        /*line-height: 1.3 !important;*/
        /*font-weight: 200 !important; !*makes font thin *!*/
        /*font-size: 1em !important;*/
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        word-break: normal;
        -webkit-hyphens: auto;
        -moz-hyphens: auto;
        -ms-hyphens: auto;
        hyphens: auto;
    }

    #liveAgentChatLogText .bubble {
        position: relative;
        display: -moz-inline-stack;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0.2em 0em 0.4em 0em;
        padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #E2E8ED;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        max-width: 90%;
    }

    /*#liveAgentChatLogText .operator, #liveAgentChatLogText .client, #liveAgentChatLogText .system {*/
        /*margin-bottom: 10px;*/
        /*clear: both;*/
        /*position: relative;*/
        /*width: 100%;*/
        /*-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;*/
        /*-moz-box-sizing: border-box;*/
        /*box-sizing: border-box;*/
    /*}*/

    #liveAgentChatLogText .timestamp {
        font-size: 0.75em;
        color: #929A9D;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

</style>

<div style="top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; position: absolute;">
    <liveAgent:clientChat>
        <div style="top: 30px; left: 5px; right: 5px; bottom: 5px; position: absolute; z-index: 0;">
            <liveAgent:clientChatSaveButton/>
            <liveAgent:clientChatEndButton/>
        </div>
        <div style="top: 65px; left: 5px; right: 5px; bottom: 5px; position: absolute; z-index: 1;">
            <liveAgent:clientChatAlertMessage/>
            <liveAgent:clientChatStatusMessage/>
            <table id="waitingMessage" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>Please wait while you are connected to an available agent.</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div style="top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 41px; left: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; word-wrap: break-word; z-index: 0;">
                <liveAgent:clientChatLog agentTypingLabel="The agent is typing" showTimeStamp="true"/>
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; height: auto; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; margin-right: 67px;">
                <liveagent:clientChatInput/>
                <liveAgent:clientChatSendButton/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </liveAgent:clientChat>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the client code wasn't producing any elements with the "bubble" class, so of course the above styling wasn't working. With some patience and inspection, I was able to get the look I wanted with the following additional styles.

```
#liveAgentChatLogText .messageText {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #E2E8ED;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    max-width: 90%;
}

.operator .messageText {
    float: left;
    background-color: rgba(178, 204, 231, 0.21);

}

.client .messageText {
    float: right;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    /*background-color: rgba(204,234,182,0.21);*/
}

span.system {
    padding: 2px 10px;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: none;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #6b7173;
    line-height: 1.5 !important;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

#liveAgentChatLogText .name {
    font-weight: 500 !important;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.2;
    display: block;
    white-space: pre;
}

#liveAgentChatLogText p {
    /*line-height: 1.3 !important;*/
    /*font-weight: 200 !important; !*makes font thin *!*/
    /*font-size: 1em !important;*/
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: normal;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
}

#liveAgentChatLogText .bubble {
    position: relative;
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0.2em 0em 0.4em 0em;
    padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #E2E8ED;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    max-width: 90%;
}

#liveAgentChatLogText .operator, #liveAgentChatLogText .client, #liveAgentChatLogText .system {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```